# How can I get most visited child form Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a video app in which there is popular feature.
I want to get all the children which are most viewed in the app.
Can any one help me with this?

Comment: You have to do it manually . Add a key (count) inside each node and update the view count on each call for that particular node .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply create **view node** in Firebase and attached with all videos node when that video watched then add +1 value to **view node**. then you get all the videos with the help of **view node**

Comment: Thank you, I tried it already. There is one problem with it. first i have to add a value to compare with, if the if the view is greater than that value then call it. Then the view value will keep on increasing and even if nobody is watching that video, it will be displayed in popular.

Comment: "if nobody is watching that video, it will be displayed in popular" this is your problem?

Comment: Yes, I mean once it cross the a number of views, which will be added to database, it will remain unchanged. So even if there are no view to the video it will be displayed as popular because it has already crossed the views.

Comment: I think its simple for example you have set the value of most visited node is 5000 then get all the videos whose view node is >= 5000 and show only 5 videos which have max views if you dont want to.do that then add date in view node and check expiary if the current date is greater than 5 days then video is 5 days old then not show this video in trending and vice versa

Comment: Thank you. I got another problem. I am using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. But i am gett values as null. Would you mind if I update this question? I can't post another question for 5 days.

Comment: wait for 5 days i don't mind but you already got -3 on this question